# Manipulating VelocityView to change the Template Name

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I've been working on an enterprise scale Java application which makes uses of `Apache Velocity`.

This application basically has many *vendors* (network owners) and there may be multiple websites running under a *network* (vendor).

The front-end is rendered using `Velocity View Engine`.

### The Dilemma:

Each page in of the site has a fixed URL, but the pages are made unique by passing the request parameters, e.g., `site.html?vid=1&sid=20160109144`.

Now, I've been using a `views.properties` file to determine the template name, it has the following content.

```
#Sitepage
site.(class)=com.sarvika.simplestack.velocity.config.SimpleStackVelocityView
site.url=site.vm
```

I am using a custom `ResourceLoader` to load templates. My `ResourceLoader` expects that the template name must be in the `vendorid/siteid/template.vm` form, but since I am using a views.properties file, it is limited to `template.vm`.

### The solution so far:

I tried to make my custom `VelocityView` class by extending the Spring Framework's `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityView`, and wrote this so far...

```
public class SimpleStackVelocityView extends VelocityView {
    
    @Override
    protected void exposeHelpers(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        
        Long vendorid = RequestParameterResolver.getVendorID(request);
        Long siteid = RequestParameterResolver.getSiteID(request);
        
        if (siteid != null) {
            setUrl(siteid+"/"+getUrl());
        }
        
        if (vendorid != null) {
            setUrl(vendorid+"/"+getUrl());
        }
        
        super.exposeHelpers(model, request);
    }

}
```

I did override this method because I need to access the Servlet Request and then change the URL of the template accordingly.

### Trouble:

For the first time, it works fine, the URL is changed to `vendorid/siteid/template.vm`, but for subsequent page reloads, it changes to `vendorid/siteid/.../vendorid/siteid/template.vm`.

What changes I can make to get the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but your call to `getUrl()` in `setUrl(siteid+"/"+getUrl());` will get the current URL. So won't this mean that when you reload the page, the URL will be of the form `vendorid/siteid/template.vm` meaning subsequent calls to `getUrl()` will return `vendorid/siteid/template.vm`, and will duplicate it further on more page reloads?

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely correct... Can you suggest me a way through which I can get the desired results in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class SimpleStackVelocityView extends VelocityView {

    private final static String SEPARATOR = "/";

    @Override
    protected void exposeHelpers(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {

        Long vendorid = RequestParameterResolver.getVendorID(request);
        Long siteid = RequestParameterResolver.getSiteID(request);

        /* This always gets the last part of the path.
         * So in this case it gets "template.vm"
         * as long as that is the last part of the path
        */
        String templateName = new File(getUrl()).getName();

        StringBuffer urlBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        if (vendorid != null) {
            urlBuffer.append(vendorid);
            urlBuffer.append(SEPARATOR);
        }

        if (siteid != null) {
            urlBuffer.append(siteid);
            urlBuffer.append(SEPARATOR);
        }

        urlBuffer.append(templateName);
        setUrl(urlBuffer.toString());

        super.exposeHelpers(model, request);
    }
}
```

If the url is like `vendorid/siteid/.../vendorid/siteid/template.vm`, then `templateName` will be "template.vm". If getUrl() just returns "template.vm" (i.e. when it is first loaded), `templateName` will still be "template.vm".